# Storyboard does not start again

Tags: wpf, silverlight, storyboard

I've got a carousel that works fine on a silverlight app, it comes from this website :
[Carousel app](http://www.silverlightwpf.fr/post/2010/07/16/Silverlight-4-e28093-Developpement-de28099un-carrousel.aspx)

Now i want to convert it into a WPF app. This issue is that the storyboard does not start again when the storyboard.begin() is called in StoryBoard.Completed event

```
private Storyboard timer;
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
this.timer.Completed -= new EventHandler(timer_Completed);
this.timer.Completed += new EventHandler(timer_Completed);
this.timer.Begin();
}
void timer_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
///Code to animate the carousel
this.timer.Begin();
}
```

The storyboard is initialized in the OnApplyTemplate, retrieving it by is name defined in xaml

Only one Completed event occurs

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Did you clip some code out of here? I'd guess it isn't actually getting to the Begin() call at the end of timer_Completed, possibly some exception happening before that.

Comment: No exception is thrown, nothing in output. The code ommited in the time completed doesn't throw any exception (i tried without that code too)

Comment: weird I do this all of the time... this line seems a bit odd: this.timer.Completed -= new EventHandler(timer_Completed);